# FadeIn / FadeOut custom slideshow programming error

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to get a 'fade-in' or 'fade-out' effect in the slideshow of this website: [www.2eenheid.de](http://www.2eenheid.de). I tried the code blow, the background image should fade but instead it only fades the menu item. I understand its probably somewhere in this line `$('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function(){`.

How can i keep this hover function WHILE having the fade on the background image? Anyone any ideas?

**EDIT**
I only want the background image to fade. Not the menu items.

**The Javascript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var imgsrc = '';
        $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function(){

          $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
          $('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url('+$(this).attr('src')+')' });
           imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');

         }, function(){
          $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
          $('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url('+imgsrc+')' });
    });

    });
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
            <div id="slideshow-main">
                    <ul class="slideshow-menu">
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('supportenbeheer')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a title="Support / Beheer" href="/supportenbeheer" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Support / Beheer</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('implementatie')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/implementatie" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Implementatie</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('cloud')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/cloud" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Cloud</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('webhosting-en-hosting')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/webhosting-en-hosting" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Webhosting / Hosting</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('unit4-multivers')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/unit4-multivers" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Unit4 Multivers</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why are you adding two different jQuery libraries? 1.8.3 and at the end of the headers, 1.6.2.

Comment: so you want to fade both the menu item and the slide image?

Comment: No, only the slide image. Menu item not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var imgsrc = '';
    $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
        imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');
        var newImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'
            }).fadeIn('slow');
        });

    }, function () {
        $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).css({
                'background-image': imgsrc
            }).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. You solved all my problems. Just one question though: when I hover on all the menu items for a couple of times the background image fades a lot until it disappears. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Glad to help. You could try adding `.stop()` before calling `fadeIn()`

Comment: I tried adding it in all kinds of different place. But won't work, any other suggestions?

Comment: You could try `.stop(true)` to clear the animation queue but I can't seem to reproduce the behavior in Chrome, when I hover over all items multiple times I only get one animation as is desirable. Also `fadeIn('slow');` is equivalent to `fadeTo('slow', 1);` I noticed you changed that, either way is fine.